# How to install Directx9 for Wine?

Tags: fedora, windows, wine, winetricks, directx

I'd like to try playing League of Legends on Fedora. To do so, I installed Lutris, Wine and Winetricks. I installed LoL from the [Lutris packages](https://lutris.net/games/league-of-legends/).

During the installation, the installer tells me that Directx9 is not found and necessary to run the game:

[image]

After a long search on the Internet, the solution would be to use Winetricks and install the library, however it doesn't work, it seems to be obsolete:

[image]

It suggests me to install instead each component individually, which I tried to do (still with Winetricks) by installing all the dlls related to Directx9, but it doesn't change anything, some of these libs are also obsolete.

How to install Directx9 under Fedora, for Wine, in order to play to League of Legends?

Comment: Are you able to install a newer DirectX version?

Comment: From Winetricks, no, this is the only version proposed (but obsolete). I haven't found any other way to install this library, for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**2 Answers to your question:**
To install native directx components with winetricks you need to know which ones you want and then do something like `winetricks d3dx9_24` to get that one.

If you want it all you can use the `wine uninstaller`. Just press the install button and select the directx_*_redist.exe and install it.

**The solution to running League of Legends**

You don't need to install native directx.
You will find good and tested instructions to run League of Legends (and most other programs, too) on the [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=37896&iTestingId=106957).